# One dropdownlist depending on the other

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, character-encoding, drop-down-menu

I develop a php web page that contains two dropdownlists (select tags) as one of them used to display the car types like Toyota, Nissan, Chevrolet and so on.

```
Toyota
Nissan
Chevrolet
```

The other should be used to display the car models like Toyota Camry, Toyota Corrolla, Toyota Cressida, Toyota Eco and son on depeding on the Car Type selected from the first dropdownlist.

I use PHP as a development language plus Sybase as database and I connect to it using ODBC.
I use Windows-1256 as Character Encoding as my displayed data is Arabic.

I try to use Ajax to implement that but I do not know how as I used Ajax before to return one value only but in this case I need to reply with some database records in the following format:-

```
15 "Toyota Camry"
16 "Toyota Corrolla"
17 "Toyota Cressida"
18 "Toyota Eco"
```

plus that the data is sent in arabic not in English as listed above so the list may be as the following:-

```
15 "تويوتا كامري"
16 "تويوتا كرولا"
17 "تويوتا كرسيدا"
18 "تويوتا إيكو"
```

how I can do that using Ajax and make sure that the Arabic text will be displayed well?

I wait your answer and help and Thanks in advance .....

My Code is written in the following to make things more clear and be useful for others and to get the right answer:

***The first file***

```
showCarData.php File (Saved as ANSI PHP File)
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
$('#selectCarType').change(function ()
{ 
$('#selectCarModel option').remove();
$.ajax(
{
url: "getCarModels.php", 
dataType: 'json', 
data: { CarType: $('#selectCarType').val() }, 
async: true,
success: function(result)
{   
//var x = eval(result);
$.each(result, function(key, value) { $('#selectCarModel').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>'); } );
}
});
$('#selectCarModel').show(); 
});
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<select id="selectCarType">     
<option value="0" selected="selected">select car type</option>
<?php
//Connecting To The Database and getting $conn Variable       
$conn = odbc_connect("database","username","password");
//Connection Check
if (!$conn)
{
echo "Database Connection Error: " . $conn;
}
$sqlCarTypes = "SELECT DISTINCT CarTypeID AS CarTypeCode, CarTypeDesc AS CarTypeName FROM tableCarTypes ORDER BY CarTypeDesc ASC";
$rsCarTypes = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlCarTypes);
if (!$rsCarTypes)
{
echo "<option class='CarType' value='n' >Not Available</option>";
}                                   
else
{                                   
while ( odbc_fetch_row($rsCarTypes) )
{
//Assigning The Database Result Set Rows To User-Defined Varaiables
$CarTypeCode = odbc_result($rsCarTypes,"CarTypeCode");
$CarTypeName = odbc_result($rsCarTypes,"CarTypeName");
//Creating the options
echo '<option class="CarType" style="color:#060;" value="'. $CarTypeCode . '"';
echo '>' . $CarTypeName . '</option>' . "\n";               
}                                   
}
odbc_close($conn);
?>
</select>
<select id="selectCarModel">        
<option value="0" selected="selected">select car model</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

***and the other file is***

```
getCarModels.php File (Saved as ANSI PHP File)

<?PHP
//determine the Characterset
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1256');

//Recieve CarType variable
$CarType =  $_GET['CarType'];
// initialize an array that will hold the rows 
$result = array();

if ($CarType != Null)
{
//Connecting To The Database and getting $conn Variable       
$conn = odbc_connect("database","username","password");
//Connection Check
if (!$conn)
{
echo "Database Connection Error: " . $conn;
}
$sqlCarModels = "SELECT DISTINCT CarModelID AS CarModelCode, CarModelDesc AS CarModelName FROM tableCarTypes WHERE CarTypeID='$CarType' ORDER BY CarModelDesc ASC ";
$rsCarModels  = odbc_exec($conn,$sqlCarModels);
if ( $rsCarModels )
{
while ( odbc_fetch_row($rsCarModels) )
{
$CarModelCode = odbc_result($rsCarModels,"CarModelCode");
$CarModelName = odbc_result($rsCarModels,"CarModelName");
$CarModelName = utf8_encode($CarModelName);
$result [$CarModelCode] = $CarModelName;
}
}
else
{
echo "No Data";
}
odbc_close($conn);
}
//send the result in json encoding
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

I hope this clear what I asked about and that any one could help me finding where is the error or the thing I miss to get the output in a proper format instead of the strange symbols and characters that could not be read as it shows in the second dropdown list.

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: What is the encoding of the tables?

Comment: The encoding of the database is UTF-8

Comment: I cannot, then, understand how you print stuff on the page. I don't see any conversions in `showCarData.php`

Comment: there is only one statement related to the encoding in showCarData.php <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256" /> 
the problem is in this page as it seems I need a jquery or javascript function to convert json utf-8 encoded data to windows-1256 encoded data but it seems no function like this in JS ??

Comment: Are you sure your DB tables are in UTF8 because the values should not print correctly with page encoding other than UTF8?

Comment: As you see in my code I use odbc to connect to the database and before I try to use utf-8 but I find a strange result when I view static or text file data it displays ok but when I get dynamic data from the database it displayed in strange format so I changed all the encoding of the web pages to windows-1256 so that the arabci text appears ok.

Comment: Do you know a way to make sure that the database is utf-8 encoded for more confirmation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in such scenario is the following:

1. I construct the first dropdownlist on the server, with PHP `while` over the car categories from the database, for example. I place the `id` of the category as a `value` of the `option`. The resulting HTML should look something like this:

   <select id="cars-categories">
     <option value="1">Toyota</option>
     <option value="2">Nissan</option>
     <option value="3">Chevrolet</option>
     ...
   </select>
2. Then on the page, with JavaScript, I listen for `onchange` event of the select and when occurs send the category `id` to the server
3. PHP code on the server picks the category `id` and makes a `SELECT your_cols FROM product_table WHERE cat_id = $_GET['id']`. Send the result as `JSON` with `json_encode`
4. Finally, parse the returned data with JavaScritp and fill the model dropdownlist.

Here is what the client script basically can look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cars-categories').change(function () {
        $('#car-models option').remove();
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_data.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { category: $('#cars-categories').val() },
            async: true,
            success: function(json){
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $('#car-models').append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
        $('#car-models').show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Encoding shouldn't be an issue.

**EDIT:** As requested by the author of the question, here is a simple way to get all the rows from the DB query and to send them back to the page as JSON encoded string.

```
<?php
// connect to DB
...
// initialize an array that will hold the rows
$rows = array();
// sanitize the category id. since it is an int, it is safest just to cast it to an integer
$cat_id = (int)$_GET['category'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM `models` WHERE cat_id = $cat_id");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc()){
   $rows[] = $row;
}
// do a regular print out. It is not going to the screen but will be returned as JavaScript object
echo json_encode($rows);
// you have to exit the script (or at least should not print anything else)
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Mr. Martin , all what you mentioned I have done it except the sending the data using JSON in step 3 and the parsing of data and filling the second dropdownlist in step 4. could you provide me with a complete and similar code sample and example? Thanks ..

Comment: I will update the answer with jQuery code because it is much easier than plain JavaScript. You might consider using jQuery

Comment: Ok, No problem, the difference will be in way of accessing the html elements included in the web page.

Comment: Mr. Martin , How I can assign the result set of the database query to JSON? Should I store the rows in an array then encode it using JSON or append the the result set in an option list then pass it.

Comment: Sorry for asking many questions and Thanks for your effort but When I run the code it gives me empty options list as it appears that the success: part does not run at all. also the word "json" should be the name of the passed varaiable or what?

Comment: the word `json` is the variable that holds all the `echo`-ed data from the PHP script. If you want, accept an answer for this question and paste your code in a new one. Write a comment here with the link of the new question and I will try to help you.

Comment: Mr. Martin Thanks alot it is about to work as the last bit needed is that the Model name which is arabic characters does not appear as it appears as null but the Model code appears ok ??!!

Comment: Without looking at the code, I cannot figure what the problem can be

Comment: it comes as the following in the Car Model Dropdownlist:- null null null null false although I used the correct names for the output value.CarModelCode and value.CarModelName and I tested the query in the database and gives me both results.

Comment: after this line `success: function(json){` do a `console.log(json)` and see what shows on the javascript console

Comment: It gives me something like that [{"CarModelCode":"21","CarModelName":null},{"CarModelCode":"22","CarModelName":null},{"CarModelCode":"23","CarModelName":null},{"CarModelCode":"24","CarModelName":null}] although When I run the Query on the database it gives me something like:{"CarModelCode":"21","CarModelName":"تويوتا يارس"},{"CarModelCode":"22","CarModelName":"تويوتا كرولا"},{"CarModelCode":"23","CarModelName":"تويوتا كرسيدا"},{"CarModelCode":"24","CarModelName":"تويوتا كامري"} What may cause that Json sees the CarModelName as null and could not see it as it is saved in the database?

Comment: is there a way to ensure that Json uses arabic encoding so that it displays data well. my database is utf-8 encoded and my web forms are windows-1256 encoded and saved as ansi and I could not change it to utf-8 so that arabic characters still displayed well

Comment: Try this. Change this line `echo json_encode($rows);` to `echo json_encode(utf8_encode($rows));`

Comment: I get depressed as I tried every thing related to the language and encoding but the output still in unkown format and could not be read as I tried all encoding conversaion like utf8_encode, utf8_decode, urlencode, urldecode in PHP plus escape, unescape, encodeURIComponent, and decodeURIComponent in Javascript but I get the same result but json_encode(utf8_encode($rows)); did not work as $rows is an array but I use it with the text value before appending it to the array. Thanks in advance for your effort.

Comment: in the same question as I have edited the question and added my code so that I do not ask duplicated questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512307/one-dropdownlist-depending-on-the-other

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and effort although the problem is not completely solved as now I get the second list changes according to the first list but it comes with unknown characters that could not be read. I will make sure that this is not due to the database encoding as this the last cause I doubt about and thanks again.

Comment: I will have more time during the weekend and will try to reproduce the problem. I will report back any discoveries

Comment: Thanks alot for your patience and ability to anaylze the problem till finding a solution ..